# installation of bcrypt module in node js

Tags: express, bcrypt

I am trying to install bcrypt module using npm.
every time I does that it showing the following errors as shown in below screen. [image: cmd screen after entering the command]
please someone help me to solve this problem

Comment: Please include the error message as text rather than a screenshot.

Comment: And additionally please provide the output of npm-debug.log